# Boot issue with Windows IoT over Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi3, boot, windows-iot-core-10

I have raspberry Pi 3 with Windows IoT 10 Core.
I flashed 17763 build using Dashboard.
Everything was working properly, even debugging from Visual Studio 2017, but in some moment, I found my Raspberry with boot menu:

```
[1] Default EFI Boot Application
[2] Default EFI Boot Application
[3] Shell
[4] Boot Manager
Start: _
```

I connected keyboard via USB, I press 1, but it no response...
The keyboard was working properly with Raspberry before.

Is there some other solution except reflashing the SD card?

Comment: Could you please tell me how you did so that the raspberry pi booted with boot menu?Raspberry Pi 2 nor 3 do not support TPM and so we cannot configure Lockdown scenarios. And more have you tried to cut the power and then reboot the device?

Comment: I don't know how it is happened, but it is happened... I tried to reboot several times. After all I just reflushed the SD card.

Comment: Yes, in this scenario, it indicates the OS is broken. We must to reflash the image. But you can reader the SD card and backup the important files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, only one solution I found, is to reflash the SD card.